# Action mailer link check in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actionmailer

I have in my rspec test such comparison:

```
expect(new_mail.body.encoded).to match(url_for(controller:'some_controller',action:'some_action',some_param:some_param))
```

but it fails because ActionMailer encodes html body to something like this:

```
   +<a href=3D"http://localhost:3000/some_controller/some_action/wgt1p468ersmkq=
   +gbvmfv5wgmifj13u894dfjrhc0hzczk71pcw3hrk5907iqfolc6onhxvik6apuuwgm1rng7ro=
   +rt8qih43thql3spyp5ajjdugy9jvx0xc5hvpi015z" style=3D"display: inline-block=
   +; background-color: #71B344; color: #FFF; border-radius: 4px; font-weight=
   +: bold; text-decoration: none; padding: 6px 12px; white-space: nowrap">
   +        Go to Your Account
   +      </a>
```

how to compare expected link and encoded link in mail body?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `new_mail.body.to_s` instead to get a non encoded version as indicated in a [Guide to Rails Testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers).

Also you can use Capybara to make assertions on the rendered email (or [any html fragment](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/use-capybara-on-any-html-fragment-or-page)), which is better than just using string matches if you really want to be sure that link is in there:

```
let(:email){ Capybara::Node::Simple.new(new_mail.body.to_s) }

it "has a link" do
  url = url_for(controller:'some_controller',action:'some_action',some_param:some_param)
  expect(email).to have_link('A link', href: url)
end
```

**Added:**

To get the correct part from a multipart email:

```
def get_message_part(mail, content_type)
  mail.body.parts.find { |p| p.content_type.match content_type }.body.raw_source
end

let(:email) { Capybara::Node::Simple.new(get_message_part(new_mail, /html/)) }
```

Comment: new_mail.body.to_s returns empty string, there are several attached files in email message

Comment: Ah forgot about those pesky multipart emails.

Comment: Added explaination on how to handle multipart emails